# shell fucntion cd breaks $PATH

Tags: shell, zsh

I'm trying to use script to change working directory.

in .zshrc:

```sh
source myscript
```

in myscript:

```
fucntion cdd(){
    $path=(find xxx |fzf) #just a command to get a path
    cd $path
}
zle -N cdd
bindkey '\et' cdd #Alt+t
```

I want to do something like `fzf` doing.

After I pressed <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> ,I did changed the working directory, but it seemes that my environment is broken.(I need to <kbd>Enter</kbd> to get shell promote back)

```sh
              (<---note I need to press Enter to get shell promote)
➜  c vim
zsh: command not found: vim
➜  c ls
zsh: command not found: ls
➜  c pwd
/home/xxx/document/c
➜  c echo $PATH
./document/c
➜  c
```

The last command `pwd` works well. It's strange that my $PATH changed. I can't figure out why.

Comment: `path` is a special variable in zsh. See https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#index-path

Comment: Instead of `$path=$(...)`, omit the leading `$` and use `path=$(...)`.

Comment: Oh my gosh....!  As to `$path=$()`, it's okay, I didn't notice that while I was posting the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$path=(find xxx |fzf)` is wrong.  You want:

```
mypath=$(find ...)
```

That is, omit the leading `$`.  In general, `path` is a bad name for a variable, so I've use `mypath`.  `PATH` has special meaning in all shells, and `path` is significant in `zsh`.  In particular, `path` is an array variable that consists of directories to be searched for executables. `path` and `PATH` are tied (see `typedef -T` in the `zsh` documentation), so modifying `path` effectively changes `PATH`.

Comment: That must be joke....Thanks. And with command `zle reset-prompt` I get the prompt back.

Comment: @chichow lol.  Yes, there are a lot of things about `zsh` that seem like they are a joke!

Comment: Colon-delimited variables like `PATH` are a hack necessitated by the lack of real data structures in POSIX shell (and the earlier shells on which POSIX is based). `:` is a legal character in a directory name, but prevents it from being added to your search path. Ideally, `PATH` *should* be an array; `path` provides an array interface to the variable. (Of course, it doesn't do anything to allow `:`-containing directories in the path, and actively hides the fact that it's a problem.)